# Prove a relation about the Fourier transform

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to prove this relation
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(x)^2(m^2-\frac{d^2}{dx^2})dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(m^2+k^2)\mid\hat{(\phi(k))^2}\mid\frac{dk}{2\pi}$
where $\hat\phi(k)$  is the Fourier transform of the function $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ is real function, when $\mid x\mid \rightarrow \infty$ function $\phi(x) \rightarrow 0$
I spent 5 hours on this already and couldn't come up with any solution

Comment: Hints : 1. In the first integral write correctly which function you are differentiating and what your integration variable is. 2. $\hat\phi$ can't be a function of $x$. What is the variable it depends on ? 3. Use [this well-known rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation).

Comment: What does $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(x)^2(m^2-\frac{d^2}{dx^2})dx$ mean ?